# Activate Page Down Windows Phone

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Is there a way to maybe have accessibility option so I can page down different windows on windows phone?

I'm familiar with this key on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 Mobile devices do not have a physical keyboard, and the hardware buttons (volume up, volume down and power) cannot have their function changed. Whilst the functions you describe are achievable through touch, I would advocate trialling with a demonstration device in store before purchase, if you have accessibility concerns - advice that holds true with any touch screen device, irrespective of operating system.

Of course, if you use continuum to project to a PC, its attached keyboard and mouse will give all of the keys it has, so that you could then page up/down, and task switch, etc.; Similarly, if you were to use continuum via a wired dock, there would be the option of attaching a physical keyboard and mouse as well.

Comment: Just curious - would a keyboard directly attached to the phone (via USB or Bluetooth) work for this?

Comment: @Indrek It increases the options (i.e. allows options other than touch screen), so it does depend on the specific accessibility issue at hand, especially if you have a device that pretends to be a standard keyboard that isn't.

Comment: @RowlandShaw That essentially answers the questions, but Indrek's question is the same as mine.  If I plug up a keyboard can I page down the current screen the phone.  I know it doesn't work on Android and iPhones.