# How to run Windows 10 Mobile on a PC?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I would like to demo Widows 10 Mobile before buying one to test out different features.

Is there a way to do this on my desktop maybe?

Comment: Are there specific features you want to try out? There are options, but not everything would be available.

Comment: @RowlandShaw just trying to answer [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16293/continuum-make-it-look-like-old-windows) question and [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/activate-page-down-windows-phone).  Just figured if there was an emulator I could test out these features myself.  Also it would be helpful for me to test out app features to insure whether or not it is well supported and or has similar Android or iPhone features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an emulator included in the development tools for Windows Mobile ([For which, the [community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is available free of charge); apparently the emulator [can also be downloaded separately](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) for a smaller download.

The emulator is aimed at developers, so some tasks, such as downloading from the store or making a call are restricted compared to a real phone.